# Binomial Theorem :: Confusion with Wiki Entry

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I wanted an expansion of $(1+x)^n$ and refered [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Binomial_coefficients) but I don't understand why there is a condition of $|x|<1$.

In general, for the series, the condition is not required am I right or am I missing something subtle?

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ordinary Binomial Theorem, where $n$ is a **non-negative integer**, there is no $|x|\lt 1$ restriction. In the *generalization* of the ordinary Binomial Theorem to situations where $n$ is not necessarily a non-negative integer, you get an *infinite series* that only converges if $|x|\lt 1$.